# SQL Server check if particular field is updated in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with following structure

```
    UpdateDate                Rate      
    2015-08-26 00:00:00.000   310.000000    
    2016-06-02 00:00:00.000   310.000000
    2017-02-01 00:00:00.000   310.000000
    2017-09-15 00:00:00.000   320.000000
    2018-01-31 00:00:00.000   310.000000
    2018-02-16 00:00:00.000   310.000000
    2018-02-23 00:00:00.000   310.000000
    2018-03-09 00:00:00.000   310.000000
    2018-04-15 00:00:00.000   320.000000
```

I am passing FromDate as report criteria.

I want to get only those rows in which Rate field is greater than previous rate after FromDate criteria.

For example, if I pass 2018-04-01 as FromDate selection criteria,
then I will get following output becuase on 2018-04-15 rate is greater than that on 2018-03-09

```
    2018-04-15 00:00:00.000   320.000000
```

But if I pass 2018-05-01 as FromDate parameter, then I will not get any output as
Rate is not updated from 2018-05-01 till today.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you need to use the 'lag' command

Answer (score 0):

This uses window functions:

```
declare @test table ([UpdateDate] datetime, [Rate] Decimal(9,6))
insert into @test values
      ('2015-08-26 00:00:00.000', 310.000000)    
    , ('2016-06-02 00:00:00.000', 310.000000)
    , ('2017-02-01 00:00:00.000', 310.000000)
    , ('2017-09-15 00:00:00.000', 320.000000)
    , ('2018-01-31 00:00:00.000', 310.000000)
    , ('2018-02-16 00:00:00.000', 310.000000)
    , ('2018-02-23 00:00:00.000', 310.000000)
    , ('2018-03-09 00:00:00.000', 310.000000)
    , ('2018-04-15 00:00:00.000', 320.000000)

declare @date as date = '2018-04-01'
;with cte1 as (select [UpdateDate], [Rate], iif(lag(Rate) OVER (ORDER BY [UpdateDate]) < [Rate], 1, 0) as [Changed] from @test),
cte2 as (Select top 1 * from cte1 where [UpdateDate] > @date order by [UpdateDate])
select [UpdateDate], [Rate] from cte2 where [Changed] = 1

set @date = '2018-03-01'
;with cte1 as (select [UpdateDate], [Rate], iif(lag(Rate) OVER (ORDER BY [UpdateDate]) < [Rate], 1, 0) as [Changed] from @test),
cte2 as (Select top 1 * from cte1 where [UpdateDate] > @date order by [UpdateDate])
select [UpdateDate], [Rate] from cte2 where [Changed] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it's resolved.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, LAG(Rate, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY UpdateDate) AS PrevRate
    FROM #TempRate
    ) A
WHERE Rate > PrevRate
```